# Download file like Android Market does

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask

I am going to implement a function that will download a large file (about 50MB) in background.

I would like to do it like Android Market - I mean when user will start downloading a file, it will appear in status bar with all that progress bar and notify my application when it will be finished.

Could you provide me some hints ? I know that my question is not a high quality but I have been doing research before and simply I have no keywords to search any solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This is just a small overview to give you a few keywords.*

First of all, how to create a notification should be pretty straightforward and is well documented. If you don't know how to create a normal notification, check out [Status Bar Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

The next step is to create a notification with a custom layout that contains a `ProgressBar` *(since there is no prebuilt layout for this afaik)*, which is also documented on the [same page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView). Once you have created `Notification` instance for that, you should keep the reference and use it to update your `ProgressBar` via

```
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.yourprogressbar, 100, 42, false);
nm.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

*`nm` is a `NotificationManager` reference here, also see [RemoteViews.setProgressBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setProgressBar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)*

That's basically the UI-side of things. To actually download a file in the background you should make use of a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that utilizes an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) *(since services run in the UI-thread - the name misleads often)*. You can use `AsyncTask.publishProgress()` to send download progress updates to the UI-thread and update your progress bar inside `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()`.

Comment: i have done like above, but from Setting->Application -> Manage App -> MyApp if i click Force stop then my service is getting stopped. its not happening in Android market download. Can u tell me how to create a service android market does.

Comment: @abbas That's not possible for a normal app. The market is a system-app, which has special rights. Normal apps can't do this for security reasons, the user has to be able to stop such apps at any time in case they contain malware.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @alextsc's answer, if you are only supporting API Level 9 and higher, you can use [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), which handles all of this for you, including details like connectivity changes (e.g., WiFi->3G). But, that's only available on Android 2.3+.

Comment: I have to use API Level 7, but I'll keep it in my mind. Thank you !